# Copy the result of C-x C-e instead of inserting it into buffer

Tags: eval, eval-expression

Is there a builtin mechanism that copies the result of `C-x C-e` rather than inserting it into the buffer with the non-negative prefix. I think this would have been more useful by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun my-eval-last-sexp ()
  (interactive)
  (elisp--eval-last-sexp nil)
  (let (result)
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer " *Echo Area 0*")
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (setq result (read (current-buffer))))
    (kill-new (format "%s" result))))
```

What's inserted into the echo area by `elisp--eval-last-sexp` is the resulting value (which is what you want copied to the `kill-ring`).

But in the case of a number, for example, what's inserted there also includes the number written in different ways (octal, hexadecimal, character).

That's why I used `read`, and then converted that to a string, instead of just picking up the text in the echo area directly. IOW, in that specific case more than just the value is inserted in the echo area - more than what we want copied to the `kill-ring`.

Comment: Is the result thrown by `elisp--eval-last-sexp`  the same as what gets inserted into the echo area?  If so, would it be possible to skip collecting the data from the echo area?

Comment: It sort of does and I get the idea. Although, it strips the double quotes from string outputs.

Comment: @lawlist: What's inserted into the echo area is the resulting value, yes, but in the case of, e.g., a number, what's inserted there also includes the number written in different ways. That's why I used `read`, and then converted that to a string, instead of just picking up the text in the echo area directly. IOW, in that specific case more than just the value is inserted in the echo area - more than what OP wants in the `kill-ring`.

Comment: @lawlist: There may be a way to not bother with the echo area, or a way to prevent it from printing the extra stuff there. But I didn't find such a way, looking quickly; it looks like that behavior is pretty much hard-coded.

Comment: @Drew -- thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @lawlist: I added that explanation to the answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable.)